# Dynamic Method Call from a Class in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can a method be called dynamically from a class in ES6?

In ES5 and lower I can do this with the following. [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dqk8n3xk/)

```
var App = function() {

    var that = this;

    this.init = function() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('call-method');

        for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                that['method' + this.dataset.method](this);
            });
        }
    };

    this.methodOne = function(element) {
        console.log(element.innerText);
    };

    this.methodTwo = function(element) {
        console.log(element.innerText);
    };

};

(function() {
    var app = new App();

    app.init();
}());
```

When I try to do the same in ES6 I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: not a function`. Is this possible in ES6 or am I doing something wrong here? [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dqk8n3xk/1/)

```
'use strict';

class App {

    constructor() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('call-method');

        for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                this.constructor['method' + this.dataset.method](this); // Uncaught TypeError: not a function
                App['method' + this.dataset.method](this); // Uncaught TypeError: not a function
            });
        }
    }

    methodOne(element) {
        console.log(element.innerText);
    }

    methodTwo(element) {
        console.log(element.innerText);
    }

}

(function() {
    new App();
}());
```

Comment: Uh, you've not been using the exact same code, you've left out `var that = this` (which is essential)? Also why are you now trying to call those methods as if they were static (they're not)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how ES6 classes work. Your first strategy is not going to work, because this.constructor is a method, not a reference to any constructor class. The second won't work, because that would only reference a static method.

Instead:

```
constructor() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('call-method');

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            this['method' + e.target.dataset.method](e);
        });
    }
}
```

Also [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are going to be a better way to bind the event.

Edit: Updated your fiddle to show it in action - http://jsfiddle.net/dqk8n3xk/3/

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
'use strict';

class App {

    constructor() {
        var that = this;

        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('call-method');

        for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                that['method' + this.dataset.method](this);
            });
        }
    }

    methodOne(element) {
        console.log(element.innerText);
    }

    methodTwo(element) {
        console.log(element.innerText);
    }

}

(function() {
    new App();
}());
```

as shown in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dcj65m0e/4/)